# Best Regular Expression for Email Format Validation with ASP.NET 3.5 Validation

Tags: asp.net, regex

I've used both of the following Regular Expressions for testing for a valid email expression with ASP.NET validation controls. I was wondering which is the better expression from a performance standpoint, or if someone has better one.

```
 - \w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*
 - ^([0-9a-zA-Z]([-\.\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z])*@([0-9a-zA-Z][-\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z]\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,9})$
```

I'm trying avoid the "exponentially slow expression" problem described on the [BCL Team Blog](https://web.archive.org/web/20140422045050/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2005/02/10/370690.aspx).

**UPDATE**

Based on feedback I ended up creating a function to test if an email is valid:

```
Public Function IsValidEmail(ByVal emailString As String, Optional ByVal isRequired As Boolean = False) As Boolean
    Dim emailSplit As String()
    Dim isValid As Boolean = True
    Dim localPart As String = String.Empty
    Dim domainPart As String = String.Empty
    Dim domainSplit As String()
    Dim tld As String

    If emailString.Length >= 80 Then
        isValid = False
    ElseIf emailString.Length > 0 And emailString.Length < 6 Then
        'Email is too short
        isValid = False
    ElseIf emailString.Length > 0 Then
        'Email is optional, only test value if provided
        emailSplit = emailString.Split(CChar("@"))

        If emailSplit.Count <> 2 Then
            'Only 1 @ should exist
            isValid = False
        Else
            localPart = emailSplit(0)
            domainPart = emailSplit(1)
        End If

        If isValid = False OrElse domainPart.Contains(".") = False Then
            'Needs at least 1 period after @
            isValid = False
        Else
            'Test Local-Part Length and Characters
            If localPart.Length > 64 OrElse ValidateString(localPart, ValidateTests.EmailLocalPartSafeChars) = False OrElse _
               localPart.StartsWith(".") OrElse localPart.EndsWith(".") OrElse localPart.Contains("..") Then
                isValid = False
            End If

            'Validate Domain Name Portion of email address
            If isValid = False OrElse _
               ValidateString(domainPart, ValidateTests.HostNameChars) = False OrElse _
               domainPart.StartsWith("-") OrElse domainPart.StartsWith(".") OrElse domainPart.Contains("..") Then
                isValid = False
            Else
                domainSplit = domainPart.Split(CChar("."))
                tld = domainSplit(UBound(domainSplit))

                ' Top Level Domains must be at least two characters
                If tld.Length < 2 Then
                    isValid = False
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Else
        'If no value is passed review if required
        If isRequired = True Then
            isValid = False
        Else
            isValid = True
        End If
    End If

    Return isValid
End Function
```

Notes:

- IsValidEmail is more restrictive about characters allowed then the RFC, but it doesn't test for all possible invalid uses of those characters

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best Regular Expression for Email Validation in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16167983/best-regular-expression-for-email-validation-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you're wondering why this question is generating so little activity, it's because there are so many other issues that should be dealt with before you start thinking about performance.  Foremost among those is whether you should be using regexes to validate email addresses at all--and the consensus is that you should not.  It's much trickier than most people expect, and probably pointless anyway.

Another problem is that your two regexes vary hugely in the kinds of strings they can match.  For example, the second one is anchored at both ends, but the first isn't; it would match "`>>>>foo@bar.com<<<<`" because there's something that looks like an email address embedded in it.  Maybe the framework forces the regex to match the whole string, but if that's the case, why is the second one anchored?

Another difference is that the first regex uses `\w` throughout, while the second uses `[0-9a-zA-Z]` in many places.  In most regex flavors, `\w` matches the underscore in addition to letters and digits, but in some (including .NET) it also matches letters and digits from every writing system known to Unicode.

There are many other differences, but that's academic; neither of those regexes is very good.  See [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html) for a good discussion of the topic, and a much better regex.

Getting back to the original question, I don't see a *performance* problem with either of those regexes.  Aside from the nested-quantifiers anti-pattern cited in that BCL blog entry, you should also watch out for situations where two or more adjacent parts of the regex can match the same set of characters--for example,

```
([A-Za-z]+|\w+)@
```

There's nothing like that in either of the regexes you posted.  Parts that are controlled by quantifiers are always broken up by other parts that aren't quantified.  Both regexes will experience some avoidable backtracking, but there are many better reasons than performance to reject them.

EDIT: So the second regex *is* subject to catastrophic backtracking; I should have tested it thoroughly before shooting my mouth off.  Taking a closer look at that regex, I don't see why you need the outer asterisk in the first part:

```
[0-9a-zA-Z]([-.\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z])*
```

All that bit does is make sure the first and last characters are alphanumeric while allowing some additional characters in between.  This version does the same thing, but it fails much more quickly when no match is possible:

```
[0-9a-zA-Z][-.\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z]
```

That would probably suffice to eliminate the backtracking problem, but you could also make the part after the "@" more efficient by using an atomic group:

```
(?>(?:[0-9a-zA-Z][-\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z]\.)+)[a-zA-Z]{2,9}
```

In other words, if you've matched all you can of substrings that look like domain components with trailing dots, and the next part doesn't look like a TLD, don't bother backtracking.  The first character you would have to give up is the final dot, and you know `[a-zA-Z]{2,9}` won't match that.

Comment: I've been debating creating a Custom Validator, with a Server side check using a non RegEx email test. After testing, I found the second expression can create an "exponentially slow expression" (given the right input) with either JavaScript or in with .NET process on the Server, in which the processing creates what appears to be frozen process.

Answer (score 8):

We use this RegEx which has been tested in-house against 1.5 million addresses. It correctly identifies better than 98% of ours, but there are some formats that I'm aware of that it would error on.

```
^([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$
```

We also make sure that there are no EOL characters in the data since an EOL can fake out this RegEx. Our Function:

```
Public Function IsValidEmail(ByVal strEmail As String) As Boolean
    ' Check An eMail Address To Ensure That It Is Valid
    Const cValidEmail = "^([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$"   ' 98% Of All Valid eMail Addresses
    IsValidEmail = False
    ' Take Care Of Blanks, Nulls & EOLs
    strEmail = Replace(Replace(Trim$(strEmail & " "), vbCr, ""), vbLf, "")
    ' Blank eMail Is Invalid
    If strEmail = "" Then Exit Function
    ' RegEx Test The eMail Address
    Dim regEx As New System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(cValidEmail)
    IsValidEmail = regEx.IsMatch(strEmail)
End Function
```

Comment: This needs to be updated for longer TLDs now.  There are many more TLDs available that are over 6 characters now.  I set mine to 20.

^([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,20}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$

http://newgtlds.icann.org/en/program-status/delegated-strings

Comment: Our database is the primary reason that the email address is defined as short as it is. The database was originally built back in the 90's and it was matched to MS-Dynamics which added further complications.

Answer (score 2):

I am a newbie, but I tried the following and it seemed to have limited the ".xxx" to only two occurrences or less, after the symbol '@'.

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9._%-]*@(?:[a-zA-Z0-9-])+(\.+[a-zA-Z]{2,4}){1,2})$
```

Note: I had to substitute single '\' with double '\\' as I am using this reg expr in R.

Answer (score 1):

These don't check for all allowable email addresses according to the [email address RFC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E-mail_address#RFC_specification).

Comment: Do you have a RegEx or a series of them that would?

Comment: Here's a start...:
    /([!#-'*+.-9=?A-Z^-~-]{1,64}|"[^"]{1,62}")@[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9.-]{1,255}/

In the first part, the period cannot be first or last.

Answer (score 1):

I let MS to do the work for me:

```
Public Function IsValidEmail(ByVal emailString As String) As Boolean
    Dim retval As Boolean = True
    Try
        Dim address As New System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(emailString)
    Catch ex As Exception
        retval = False
    End Try
    Return retval
End Function
```

Comment: Good idea, I didn't realize that the address object had built-in validation. My only concern is that you have to use Exception management for normal workflow.

Comment: It doesn't, I've tried that one with email addresses there were not valid (something@.com I believe was one of them). No exception, it managed to create the object. This was in C#, but assuming VB is the same.

Comment: Andreas, of course it's the same in VB. There is one MailAddress class in the .NET framework, and you can use it from any .NET language.

Comment: FormatException when the argument is not in a recognized format (MSDN). Unfortunately, no details about what is acceptable or not...

Answer (score 1):

For server side validation, I found Phil Haack's solution to be one of the better ones. His attempt was to stick to the RFC:

```
string pattern = @"^(?!\.)(""([^""\r\\]|\\[""\r\\])*""|"
            + @"([-a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~]|(?<!\.)\.)*)(?<!\.)"
            + @"@[a-z0-9][\w\.-]*[a-z0-9]\.[a-z][a-z\.]*[a-z]$";

Regex regex = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
return regex.IsMatch(emailAddress);
```

Details:
http://blog.degree.no/2013/01/email-validation-finally-a-net-regular-expression-that-works/

Answer (score 0):

Just to contribute, I am using this regex.

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9._%-]*@(?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,4})$
```

Comment: It validates hshsh@hn.cm.cm.cm.cm.cm  which is wrong buddy...is it possible to restrict user to enter more than 2 dots after @

Answer (score 0):

The thing about it is the specifications are changing with each domain extension that is introduced.

You sit here mod your regex, test, test, test, and more testing.  You finally get what you "think" is accurate then the specification changes... You update your regex to account for what the new requirements are..

Then someone enters aa@aa.aa and you've done all that work for what?  It walks through your fancy regex.. bummer!

You may as well just check for a single @, and a "." and move on.  I assure you, you will not get someones email if they do not want to give it up.  You'll get garbage or their hotmail account they never check and couldn't care less about.

I've seen in many cases this goes horribly wrong and a client calls up because their own email address is rejected because of a poorly crafted regex check.  Which as mentioned shouldn't have even been attempted.

Answer (score 0):

TextBox :-

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtemail" runat="server" CssClass="form-control pantxt" Placeholder="Enter Email Address"></asp:TextBox>
```

Required Filed validator:

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator9" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtemail" ErrorMessage="Required"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

Regular Expression for email validation :

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="validateemail" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtemail" ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*" ErrorMessage="Invalid Email"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

Use this regular expression for email validation in asp.net