# Best Regular Expression for Email Validation in C#

Tags: c#, regex, email-validation

I have seen a multitude of regular expressions for different programming languages that all purport to validate email addresses.  I have seen many comments saying that the expressions in question do not work for certain cases and that they are either too strict or too permissive.  What I'm looking for is a regular expression that I can use in my C# code that is definitive.

The best thing I have found is this

```
^([\w\.\-]+)@([\w\-]+)((\.(\w){2,3})+)$
```

Is there something better?

Comment: I don't know too much on the topic, but i've read throughout SO that you SHOULDN'T use regex for email validation.

Comment: http://ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html

Comment: Do not regex email addresses. Send a confirmation email to verify their email address is correct.

Comment: That regex actually fails a valid email address. So, you definitely need something better. Sorry, I don't know of any.

Comment: *Is there something better?*: If you mean something that actually works, then yes. The regex you posted will not match a wide range of valid email addresses.

Comment: There is no definitive validation for email addresses for any situation. Any pattern will either be too strict or too permissive in differernt situations. You simply have to pick one pattern that validates what you need in each separate situation. Even a pattern that follows the RFC standard is too strict in some situations, as it won't allow some email addresses that are actually in use.

Comment: Here is a better solution directly from our friends at Microsoft: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/01escwtf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: The question specified as original is for php. The regex syntax for different languages are different, so this question is not a duplicate of php question. However the question should be closed as a duplicate of [Regex Email validation](//stackoverflow.com/q/5342375) (C#)

Comment: This is not a duplicate - C# regexes are a slightly different flavour to php and the referenced SO question cannot be used directly in C#

Answer (score 178, accepted):

> Email address: RFC 2822 Format 
>   Matches a normal email address. 
>   Does not check the top-level domain.
>  Requires the "case insensitive"
>   option to be ON.

```
[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?
```

Usage :

```
bool isEmail = Regex.IsMatch(emailString, @"\A(?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?)\Z", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Comment: I'm sorry, how should I turn on "case insensitive" option?

Comment: Does this allow UTF-8 characters in the local part (e.g. German umlauts like Ä, ü, ö, or the ß)?

Comment: So it won't work for an internationally operating company. Any ideas for that problem? Or a link?

Comment: @connexo, will check what i can do, a little occupied atm!

Comment: are those utf-8 characters valid emails?

Comment: MSDN refers this. And it works corectly
`https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/01escwtf(v=vs.110).aspx`

Comment: Alexandr's link above doesn't work for me for some reason. [Here's a direct link.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/01escwtf.aspx)

Comment: Microsoft's algorithm references says that `simon-@hotmail.com` is not valid where it in fact is

Comment: MIcrosoft algorithm also fails on mail addresses where the local name ends with underscore, while this is perfectly valid. Example: mymail_@outlook.com.

Comment: Another address that should not be valid: user.name@hotmail.com

Comment: The regex return true for this email - > "email@111.222.333.44444"

Comment: `email@[123.123.123.123]` is valid email but this regex can't match it

Comment: What do the "\A(?:" and ")\Z" modifiers in the beginning and end of the C# string mean?

Comment: Okay, I figured out that \A and \Z are C#-specific anchors, but whay not just use ^ and $, e.g. "^[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?$"

Comment: The forward slash "/" in the regex is causing an error, so you need to escape that by adding "\" before it.

Here is the working regex:
``\A[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\z``

Also, I changed `\Z` to `\z`.

[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/DaROM6/1).

Answer (score 22):

First option (bad because of throw-catch, but MS will do work for you):

```
bool IsValidEmail(string email)
{
    try {
        var mail = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(email);
        return true;
    }
    catch {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Second option is read [I Knew How To Validate An Email Address Until I Read The RFC](http://haacked.com/archive/2007/08/21/i-knew-how-to-validate-an-email-address-until-i.aspx) and [RFC specification](http://ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html)

Comment: -1 `System.Net.Mail.MailAddress` approves way too many address combinations that would fail in reality and are also wrong according to the RFC spec, such as `unescaped white space@fake$com`.

Comment: If the purpose here is to send a mail with `System.Net`, then this validation is adequate

Comment: @VinayakPrabha above code probably outdated from 2013. The new domains were introduced and I don't know if Microsoft included them

Comment: agreed. The regex in the below line covers the new domains http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16167983/best-regular-expression-for-email-validation-in-c-sharp

Comment: if you pass "JB@hotmailcom" it will return true :(

Comment: I like to add some basic extra checks like `if (email.Host.EndsWith(".cmo")) { return false; }` and `if (!email.Host.Contains(".")) { return false; }`

Comment: `MailAddress` sees whitespace as an e-mail address boundary, accepts repeating periods (..) and does not require TLD. Tried it and discarded this method.

Comment: It Doesn't work :(

Answer (score 13):

This C# function uses a regular expression to evaluate whether the passed email address is syntactically valid or not.

```
public static bool isValidEmail(string inputEmail)
{
   string strRegex = @"^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}" +
         @"\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\" + 
         @".)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$";
   Regex re = new Regex(strRegex);
   if (re.IsMatch(inputEmail))
    return (true);
   else
    return (false);
}
```

Comment: This reg ex is not tested. It allows email address - somename@gmail.com.in.in.in.in.in !!!

Comment: @ParthTrivedi somename@gmail.com.in.in.in.in.in is technically a valid email address.

Answer (score 3):

Updated answer for 2019.

Regex object is thread-safe for Matching functions. Knowing that and there are some performance options or cultural / language issues, I propose this simple solution.

```
public static Regex _regex = new Regex(
    @"^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$",
    RegexOptions.CultureInvariant | RegexOptions.Singleline);

public static bool IsValidEmailFormat(string emailInput)
{
    return _regex.IsMatch(emailInput);
}
```

Alternative Configuration for Regex:

```
public static Regex _regex = new Regex(
    @"^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$",
    RegexOptions.CultureInvariant | RegexOptions.Compiled);
```

I find that compiled is only faster on big string matches, like book parsing for example. Simple email matching is faster just letting Regex interpret.

[Thread Safety And Regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/thread-safety-in-regular-expressions)
[Regex Best Practices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/best-practices)

Answer (score 1):

I would like to suggest `new EmailAddressAttribute().IsValid(emailTxt)` for additional validation before/after validating using RegEx

Remember `EmailAddressAttribute` is part of `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations namespace`.

Comment: +1. If you absolutely need a regular expression, consider `^[^@]+@[^@]+$`, which is approximate to the algorithm EmailAddressAttribute uses. Internally, EmailAddressAttribute used regular expressions up until .NET 4.7.2, when it disabled them to reduce the number of places potentially vulnerable to a ReDoS attack (https://github.com/Microsoft/dotnet/blob/master/Documentation/compatibility/aspnet-472-compat-doc.md).

Otherwise, the best way to validate an email address is to send an email to that address.

Answer (score -1):

This is my regex, it checks the format of the email address against RFC 2822 for everything except comments (in .net format):

```
^("".*""|(?>[a-zA-Z0-9!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{}\|~]|\\.)+(?>\.(?>[a-zA-Z0-9!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{}\|~]|\\.)+)*)@([a-zA-Z0-9!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{}\|~]+(?>\.[a-zA-Z0-9!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{}\|~]+)*)$
```

It allows:
"anything in quotes" or a series of specific characters possibly including an escaped character (?) with an optional dot followed by a series of specific characters possibly including an escaped character (?)
then @
then a series of specific characters with an optional dot followed by a series of specific characters

Answer (score -2):

Email Validation Regex

```
^[a-z0-9][-a-z0-9._]+@([-a-z0-9]+.)+[a-z]{2,5}$
```

Or

```
^[a-z0-9][-a-z0-9._]+@([-a-z0-9]+[.])+[a-z]{2,5}$
```

Demo Link:

https://regex101.com/r/kN4nJ0/53

Comment: "very.(),:;<>[]\".VERY.\"very@\\ \"very\".unusual"@strange.example.com is a valid email address according to RFC and does not match your regex

Comment: Chinese characters are also valid, but I don't see any solutions here that take account of that ;) perhaps you will create one for us? See you in 6 years.