# Checking for "@" and "." in string?

Tags: string, email, character

I'm building a basic contact manager, and I am wondering how one would check to see if an email address has the "@" and "." character, for validation purposes. I have been doing some looking around and I am not quite sure, would I be able to use "IndexOf" somehow? Any help would be appreciated, this is what my code looks like so far.

```
public static string GetValidEmail(string message, List<Contact> contactList)
{
    // declare variables
    string validString;
    bool duplicateEmail;

    do
    {

        duplicateEmail = false;
        //ask user for input, remove empty space from beginning/end if it exists
        Console.Write(message);
        validString = Console.ReadLine().Trim();


        //check for empty string
        while (string.IsNullOrEmpty(validString))
        {
            //display error message, ask for user input 
            Console.WriteLine("ERROR: You cannot enter an empty value, please try again");
            Console.Write(message);
            validString = Console.ReadLine();
        }
        //check for duplicate email, if duplicate is found, restart do until loop
        for (int index = 0; index < contactList.Count && duplicateEmail == false; index++)
        {
            if (contactList[index].EmailAddress.ToUpper().Equals(validString.ToUpper()))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("ERROR: You cannot enter duplicate email addresses, please try again");
                duplicateEmail = true;
            }
        }
    } while (duplicateEmail);

    return validString;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't recommend the exception catching approach. In most cases, a regex match will do a decent enough job.

```
bool isEmail = Regex.IsMatch(emailString, @"\A(?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?)\Z");
```

See
[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16168103/2381321) for details.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is exactly what you need, but i normally use a methods similar to this when i have the need to validate a email address.

```
    public bool IsValidEmail(string mail)
    {
        try
        {
            new MailAddress(mail);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```