# Email validation expression

Tags: c#, asp.net

After writing this, also while entering email it is showing an error message and it is working fine. I don't know whats going on. Any one please explain once. Thanks in advance

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="Txt5" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBox5" ValidationGroup="abc" ErrorMessage="*"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="Txt05" runat="server" ControlToValidate = "TextBox5" Display ="Dynamic" ValidationExpression="^\w+([-+.']\w+)*@domain.com$" ErrorMessage="Please enter valid email address.."></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

Comment: Try change regex http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16167983/best-regular-expression-for-email-validation-in-c-sharp

Comment: And what is the error message ?

Comment: if your ValidationExpression  is correct than try to put ValidationGroup="abc" property to RegularExpressionValidator .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please use this one as your regular expression:

```
ValidationExpression="[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@
(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?"
```

For further clarification, on how this works, please look [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html).

As it is now, your regular expression matces only email addresses with domain equal to domain and .com extension. Certainly, that's a problem, since xzxzx@yahoo.gr is a valid email address and your reg exp will not evaluate it as a valid one. (xzxzx would be some name)

Comment: @chrish549 you welcome ! Test it and let me know, if you experience any issues.

Answer (score 0):

According to your expression, it expects `@domain.com` at the end of each email address.. 
Hence, 'something@domain.com' would not show any error message.. 
Try the expression as mentioned in the post [Using a regular expression to validate an email address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address)