# Is Regex stable to use for email validation oppsed to the mailAddress Class?

Tags: c#, regex, winforms, mailaddress

I have this function of which works fine however is there and easier way to complete the validation check using the mail address class, and would it be more fitting. Thanks in advance.

```
        TextBox tb = new TextBox();
        tb.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(txtEmail_KeyDown);

        string strRegex = @"^(?("")("".+?(?<!\\)""@)|(([0-9a-z]((\.(?!\.))|[-!#\$%&'\*\+/=\?\^`\{\}\|~\w])*)(?<=[0-9a-z])@))" + @"(?(\[)(\[(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}\])|(([0-9a-z][-\w]*[0-9a-z]*\.)+[a-z0-9][\-a-z0-9]{0,22}[a-z0-9]))";

        Regex re = new Regex(strRegex); // New regex Object  created 

        // Run Checks after the enter is pressed.
        if (e.KeyCode == (Keys.Enter))
        {
            // checks for is match, if empty and length 
            if (!re.IsMatch(txtEmail.Text) || (txtEmail.Text.Equals("")) || txtEmail.Text.Length > 100)
            {
                // display messagebox with error
                MessageBox.Show("Email not correct format!!!! ");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Email Format is correct");
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: it depends what regex you use as there are so many cases to check if you want to restrict input with regex

Comment: would it more effient using the mailAddress class ? and how about the example regex above which checks all tld's also

Comment: see there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36035941/check-valid-email-address-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 2):

you can validate with the EmailAddressAttribute class pretty easily like this in c#

```
public bool ValidateEmail(string EmailToVerify)
{
  if (new EmailAddressAttribute().IsValid(EmailToVerify))
        return true;
  else 
        return false;
}
```

but to use this you need to add this **using** at the top of your c# code page

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
```

the only downside to this is that EmailAdressAttribute is not so permisive so it depends on what you want to restrict and permit

And if you need it here is the link the the msdn doc about this class :
https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.emailaddressattribute(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: how Would i go about implementing this within a windows form project?

Comment: look at S.Petrosov answer he implented it

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not stable. Since any regular expression of itself represents a finite state machine, it can, in special cases, get into an infinite loop that grafts to the server's DDOS attack.
Just use MailAddress class for validation.

UPDATE 1
After testing `MailAddress` class and `new EmailAddressAttribute().IsValid("MAIL_TEXT_HERE")` 
I came to conclusion that **EmailAddressAttribute's** Validation is working better.
You can implement it in this way, let's say that you have TextBox and Button for submit. Just add this Click event handler to buttons Click Event:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!new EmailAddressAttribute().IsValid(textBox1.Text))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Email is not valid");
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Email is valid");
    }
}
```

Comment: cheers, to write a validation function should i use the mailAddress class or store all possibilties in a collection ?

Comment: @whatdoyouNeedFromMe just use MailAddress class

Comment: How would you implement using a user input from a text box on a  winform

Comment: don`t forget about the using you need to add like i said in my answer

Comment: @Louis-RochTessier yeah, of course , just VS2017 offers to add it automatically, so I did not pay attention to this when I was writting

Comment: If your answer addresses only stability and a particular regex engine that truly implements a finite state machine, then perhaps you're correct. If at the the same time you also address convenience, consistency, previously-proven methods, etc., then your answer is also probably the best (i.e. no need to reinvent the wheel and mess with finding the "perfect" pattern... which itself is debatable).  However, the .Net regex implementation is not strictly a FSM. It is also possible to produce a multi-pattern solution, possibly contained in a time-out block, that could be considered "stable".

Comment: @CPerkins yes, I do agree with you, but it all brings with it additional checkings.