# Combining regular expressions c#

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to make simple email validation by myself. And I need to combine two patterns:

1) `@"^[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9._-]+[A-Za-z0-9]@[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z0-9.-]+[A-Za-z0-9]$"`   // allows only xxxx@xxx.xx and dot is not the first or last charachter of local and domain part

2) `@"^([^\.]|([^\.])\.[^\.])*$"` // there must not be two or more dots in a row.

In other words, I want to add to the first regex a condition that `asd.asd@asd.com` is true, but `asd..asd@asd.com` is false.

Comment: Why don't you just execute the regex for each of them separately, and not worry about combining them into one

Comment: Why reinventing the wheel? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16167983/best-regular-expression-for-email-validation-in-c-sharp

Comment: But then I'll  never know how it works;)  I could use thousands of loops instead of a regex then

Comment: Consider this: https://hackernoon.com/the-100-correct-way-to-validate-email-addresses-7c4818f24643#.bswbyuazj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^(?!.*[.][.])[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9._-]+[A-Za-z0-9]@[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9.-]+.[A-Za-z0-9.-]+[A-Za-z0-9]$
```

Just add a `lookahead` for the same.

See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/dR4pQ2/1