# How to validate email address in c# console application?

Tags: c#, console-application

I Build some simple code to fill the field like a forms. I put email input and i want to validate and if mail address was correct the code was allow to another action.

Console.Write("Enter Your Email : ");
 string acmail = Console.ReadLine();

validate the "acmail" it's a valid email adress or not

Comment: Could you share your code to see where are you solving this and what is the problem you face?

Comment: Look at [MailAddress Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.mailaddress?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16167983/best-regular-expression-for-email-validation-in-c-sharp)

Comment: check here this topic  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5342375/regex-email-validation

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# code to validate email address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1365407/c-sharp-code-to-validate-email-address)

Comment: A lot of suggestions in this thread but I suggest reading [this instead](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/how-to-verify-that-strings-are-in-valid-email-format?redirectedfrom=MSDN).

Comment: To anyone who wants to validate a mail address with RegEx : Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Demo {
   static void Main() {
      string val;

      bool validEmail = false;

      Console.Write("Enter Email: ");
      val = Console.ReadLine();

      int stringSplitCount = val.Split('@').Length;

      if(stringSplitCount > 1 && stringSplitCount <= 2) // should only have one @ symbol
        {
           stringSplitCount = val.Split('.').Length;

           if(stringSplitCount > 1)  // should have at least one . (dot)
             validEmail = true
        }

      val += (validEmail ? " is valid" ; "is invalid");

      Console.WriteLine("Your input: {0}", val);

   }
}
```

Comment: int stringSplitCount = val.split('@').count;

Comment: Above code doesn't work val.split throw the error.

Comment: updated the syntax. @Midhushan no error this time.

Comment: it's works when I remove " && stringSplitCount < 2 " from if condition. Anyway Thank You so mush. I think <2 don't need.

Comment: Thank you for highlighting the typo, it should be <= instead of = because with < operator the if condition will never be true.