# JQuery/javascript email validation with regex

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, validation, email

I have been searching around a bit for a good regex for email validation, but for most of the ones I am finding I see the people comment saying the regex is outdated, or it doesn't work... so I am hoping that someone can help me out with an email validation regex that is currently valid for all emails...

here's what I have so far : I have seen people saying that `emailReg2` is outdated and produces false positives, but haven't seen anything about `emailReg1` being outdated.

```
var emailReg1 = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,6})?$/;
var emailReg2 = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_.+-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;

function IsEmail(email) {
  var regex = //which regex do I put here?
  return regex.test(email);
}
```

any clarification is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: @PedroLobito I did... someone edited the question to say that I didn't search... that is actually a bit frustrating... I remember I specifically said in the beginning `I have been searching for some time...`

Comment: I rolled back your question, it still doesn't explain why this question isn't like yours http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/validate-email-address-in-javascript

Comment: @PedroLobito its a 5 yr old question and the first comment in the answer is : `This regex eliminates valid, in-use emails. Do not use. Google for "RFC822" or "RFC2822" to get a proper regex.`

Comment: the answers are just as valid. not to mention that email addresses haven't really changed much.

Comment: @Adjit also note that "bogus@nonexistant.com" is a valid email address.

Comment: @Pointy right, all I really want to make sure is that there is nothing harmful in the email address

Comment: Do these also validate European addresses as well? Like eva.lichtenberger@europarl.europa.eu ?

Answer (score 0):

```
function validateEmail(email) {
var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
return re.test(email);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For a regex to validate email addresses, you should look at your needs and determine if you do need something complex or something very simple.

For a simple (and hackish) regex:

```
.+?@.+?\..+
```

Going indepth:

```
.+?   # At least 1 or more character, non-greedy; matches everything before the @ sign
@     # literal @
.+?   # Same as above; matches everything before the .
\.    # literal .
.+    # match everything after
```

This doesn't work for domains like `appname.appspotmail.com` as it has multiple fullstops in it, but should suit your needs.

You can modify the above regex to accept such conditions. As mentioned, it all depends on your needs. There is no better or worse regex for email validation; there is only a regex that meets your needs perfectly and a regex that is unnecessarily verbose.

If possible, you should come up with your own regex instead of using others, as you're the only person who will know your own needs.

If you must use something that complies with the RFC, look at this extremely verbose regex: http://ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html However, I would discourage you from using that regex and instead look for a library that validates email addresses. You probably don't need to comply with the RFC, though.

If you want resources for debugging regular expressions, give http://regex101.com a try.

Comment: so would I be able to make a more complex regex... where if it fails the first time, try a different regex to check for multiple fullstops? so the next regex would be something like `.+?@.+?\..+?.+`

Comment: you would use closures. pick up a guide on regular expressions; http://www.amazon.com/Mastering-Regular-Expressions-Jeffrey-Friedl/dp/0596528124 is one of the best IMO

Answer (score -1):

The REGEX I use for Email validation is

```
^[a-zA-Z][\w\.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]@[a-zA-Z0-9][\w\.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\.]*[a-zA-Z]$
```

There are a number of REGEX questions on SO for the **Best** Email Validation.

[Best Regular Expression for Email Format Validation with ASP.NET 3.5 Validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936870/best-regular-expression-for-email-format-validation-with-asp-net-3-5-validation)

[Validate email address in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/validate-email-address-in-javascript?rq=1)

[Using a regular expression to validate an email address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address?rq=1)

From most of my research you will find plenty of REGEX that will validate **most** email addresses, but I have never found one that will catch *all* emails. You have to find the one that fits your needs the best.